# How does shared memory work behind the scene in Linux?

Tags: shared-memory

Process A created a shared memory '1234' using shmget . After this , Process A attaches the memory to itself using shmat.

Process B also attaches shared memory corresponding to '1234' to itself using shmat.

Now what does "attach" mean exactly ? Are there two copies of the same memory existing ? If not , then where exactly is this memory existing ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every process has its own virtual memory space. To simplify things a bit, you can imagine that a process has all possible memory addresses 0x00000000..0xffffffff available for itself. One consequence of this is that a process can not use memory allocated to any other process – this is absolutely essential for both stability and security.

Behind the scenes, kernel manages allocations of all processes and maps them to physical memory, making sure they don't overlap. Of course, not all addresses are in fact mapped, only those that are being used. This is done by means of pages, and with the help of memory-mapping unit in the CPU hardware.

Creating shared memory (`shmget`) allocates a chunk of memory that does not belong to any particular process. It just sits there. From the kernel's point of view, it doesn't matter who uses it. So a process has to request access to it – that's the role of `shmat`. By doing that, kernel will map the shared memory into process' virtual memory space. This way, the process can read and write it. Because it's the same memory, all processes who have "attached" to it see the same contents. Any change a process makes is visible to other processes as well.